# Determinant inequality about Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, toeplitz-matrices

Given, Toeplitz matrix $T \in R^{n \times n}$:
$$
        T=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \tau_0 & \tau_1 & \cdots & \tau_{n-1} \\
        \tau_1 & \tau_0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \tau_1 \\
        \tau_{n-1} & \cdots & \tau_1 & \tau_0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and denoted the $k$-th order leading principal submatrix of $T$ by $T_k$.

If $T$ is a positive definite matrix, how to prove the following inequality:
$$
        \det T_{k+1} \le \frac{(\det T_k)^2}{\det T_{k-1}}
$$
,where $\forall k \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$.

And, when the equality is attained?

Comment: Would the [Szegő_limit_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szegő_limit_theorems) be relevant to your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, go ahead and include your work by editing the post.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality can be rewritten as $\dfrac{\det{T_{k-1}}}{\det{T_k}}\le\dfrac{\det{T_k}}{\det{T_{k+1}}}$ or equivalently (since $X^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{adj} X}{\det X}$),
$$
(T_k^{-1})_{11}\le(T_{k+1}^{-1})_{11}.
$$
In other words, it means the $(1,1)$-th element of $T_k^{-1}$ is weakly increasing.

To prove it, write $T_{k+1}=\pmatrix{T_k&v\\ v^T&\tau_0}$. Using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we have
$$
T_{k+1}^{-1}
=\pmatrix{T_k&v\\ v^T&\tau_0}^{-1}
=\pmatrix{\left(T_k-\frac{1}{\tau_0}vv^T\right)^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}.
$$
Since $\left(T_k-\frac{1}{\tau_0}vv^T\right)^{-1}\succeq T_k^{-1}$, we have $(T_{k+1}^{-1})_{11}=\left(\left(T_k-\frac{1}{\tau_0}vv^T\right)^{-1}\right)_{11}\ge(T_k^{-1})_{11}$.